# Enable Unmanaged Debugging always causes Visual Studio crash

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-studio-2005, unmanaged

Never before had any problems with enabling unmanaged debugging.
I'm using Vista, VS Team System 2008 (9.0 30729.1 SP)
and VS 2005  Team Edition for Software Developers (8.0.50727.867).
Starting today I cannot debug unmanaged code from C#! 
I cannot even set a check on enabling unmanaged debugging for 
an empty C# console project with no unmanaged code references- as soon as I do it and start debugging the application crashes.

An error message is displayed but I cannot see it - "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close" dialog appears too fast.
That's what I see in the event log:
Faulting application devenv.exe, version 9.0.30729.1, time stamp 0x488f2b50, faulting module mscordbi.dll, version 2.0.50727.4016, time stamp 0x49cc8cfa, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00018087, process id 0xf00, application start time 0x01cb1ede1e055024.
Checking the exception code it seems to be some access problem - anybody *any* idea?
Thank you.

The error I'm probably getting is:
CORDBG_E_INTEROP_NOT_SUPPORTED